# Use one connection to an API for all pages

Tags: asp.net, api, webforms

I have an API where i only fetch data. The problem is that I can only open two connection at the time, after that the server blocks any attempts to connect again.

I have an asp.net (4.6 but it can be upgraded if necessary) WebForms application where one page uses the connection.
I would like to be able to open more versions of the same page but I would like for them to use the same connection as the first so that the server won't use more than one connection.

Is this possible? If so how?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your connection statically in the global object and instantiate it in the application_start method. You pages should then be able to share the single connection.